# In html/css hide scroll bar but arrows should work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the scroll bar but the overflown data should be accessed with the help of arrows. Can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: There is no easy way to style scroll bar as it's very browser-dependant. Maybe with some JS...

Comment: This is a very low quality post, but i have a link that might help you. https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Comment: You might want to refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/1577396).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check this [JsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/536/). If thats what is your requirement, then add the below code

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: but there are no arrows. although this is a good one.

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/537/

Comment: @mulla.azzi can you do the same horizontally with the help of arrows(keyboard). when we add scroll bar we can scroll horizontally with the help of left and right arrow keys on keyboard. so, now i want that functionality but that scrollbar should not be visible.

Comment: checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/538/

Answer (score 0):

This is just the very basic version of it, but it should get you going:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvY62/

```
$('.up').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    p.css({
        marginTop: "-=20"  
    })
});
```

Comment: @mulla.azzi ya thats what I want but its working only vertically, I want horizontally with left and right arrows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look at the code, it says marginTop, change it with marginLeft and you're fine.